# How to send an object array as args in Chaincode for hyperledger fabric

Tags: json, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have an object array like below

```
[ {"name":"heamoglobin","reading":"12"},
  {"name":"mrc","reading":"3.3"},
  {"name":"hct","reading":"33"} ]
```

I need to send this as an argument for my chaincode function. I tried stringifying the whole array
like this

```
"[{\"name\":\"heamoglobin\",\"reading\":\"12\"},{\"name\":\"mrc\",\"reading\":\"3.3\"},{\"name\":\"hct\",\"reading\":\"33\"}]"
```

but didnt get a successful transaction

Any suggestions?

Comment: For node.js did you try using JSON.stringify function?

Comment: yes but i used it only for the object array though


 "await contract.submitTransaction(
                                "createReport",
                                    uid,
                                    req.body.patientID,
                                    user[0].email,
                                    clinicProfile.centerName,
                                    date,
                                    JSON.stringify(data)
                            )"

Comment: I feel the arguments would be passed as strings. There are 6 arguments. So you pass function name + 6 strings. I assume uid, patientID and date are not strings. So that might be the issue. You must then parse correctly these arguments in the chaincode.

Comment: @ChintanRajvir I tried sending the whole object as one argument to the chaincode like this
await contract.submitTransaction(
                                "createReport",
                                JSON.stringify(
                                    uid,
                                    req.body.patientID,
                                    user[0].email,
                                    clinicProfile.centerName,
                                    date,
                                    data
                                )
                            )
didnt work

Comment: That is not the right way. You must convert arguments to strings separately like @kekomal shows in his answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must convert to string each parameter that is not already string. Something like:

```js
await contract.submitTransaction("createReport", uid, req.body.patientID, user[0].email, clinicProfile.centerName, date.toString(), JSON.stringify(data));
```

And then process suitably every parameter in your chaincode's operation (unmarshal the array, etc.).